# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression, when using v-bind

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vue-component, vue-props

I am trying to use a prop as an image source. Although when I use v-bind to call on the prop, or any object in the script for that matter, the terminal throws the error

> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

and the webpage is completely blank. Except for what is on the app.vue.

Here is the code for reference. I am using a static variable and generic string for testing, but I get the same results from using the prop. Which is the end goal

```
<template>
  <div id="HomeListing">
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img v-bind:src="require(skl)" class="card-img" alt="image unavailable">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{title_of}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{body}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{timestamp}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HomeListing',
  props: {
    src: String,
    title_of: String,
    body: String,
    timestamp: String
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      skl: 'squirel'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right approach! Only a slight change is necessary:
You need to put the `required()` into the data part, instead of the template part.

So like this - `squirel` seems to be the image (btw, it is spelled "squirrel"):

```
<template>
  <div id="HomeListing">
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img v-bind:src="skl" class="card-img" alt="image unavailable">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{title_of}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{body}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{timestamp}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HomeListing',
  props: {
    src: String,
    title_of: String,
    body: String,
    timestamp: String
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      skl: require('squirel')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When I do that it treats it as a dependency and starts looking for 'squirel' as a dependency instead of the desired string. Which of course throws the missing dependency error. I want 'squirel' to end up being a generic string passed as a prop.